# How to convert Stream to Image?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF service and I send img by parameter in Stream, and I want save the image that I sent in file in my server, in this case is localhost.

Can you help me?

```
Public Function UploadStream(ByVal stream As Stream) As Byte() Implements IService1.UploadStream

    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(9999) {}
    Dim bytesRead As Integer, totalBytesRead As Integer = 0

    Do
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead
    Loop While bytesRead > 0

    Dim imagememorystream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(buffer)
    Dim imgFromStream As Image = Image.FromStream(imagememorystream)

    Return buffer

End Function
```

If I remove this code: `Dim imagememorystream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(buffer)
        Dim imgFromStream As Image = Image.FromStream(imagememorystream)`,
the function returns the bytearray, when I add him the WCF service doesn't work.

> Erro do Pedido
>   O servidor encontrou um erro ao processar o pedido. A mensagem de exceção é 'O parâmetro não é válido.'. Consulte os registos do servidor para obter mais detalhes. O rastreio da pilha de exceções é:
>   em System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
>   em WcfService2.Service1.UploadStream(Stream stream)
>   em C:\Users\d-sil\source\repos\WcfService2\WcfService2\Service1.svc.vb:line 40
>   em SyncInvokeUploadStream(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>   em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>   em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much about vb but i did the same thing in c#. at first you need to return Stream instead of byte array and the simply return the image like this:

```
var Image = new MemoryStream(image) { Position = 0 };
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/*";
return Image;
```